# Async Await Promise does not work : promiseresult is undefined

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, speech-synthesis

I have not being able to use the `getvoices()` function from the `speechsynthesis` framework.
My basic idea is to be able to click on the document and be able to read the text of the element  in Spanish. Therefore, I am trying to use the promise and await paradigm to set the voice variable upon loading the document based on the list of available voices.
What am I missing? thanks!

```js
var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
function getVoices() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices()
            resolve(voices)
    })
}
async function getVoz() {
    const Voces = await getVoices();
    for(voz of Voces){
        if (voz.lang=="es-ES"){
            return voz
        }
    }
}
var voice = getVoz()

function sayit(){
  var div = document.getElementById('main')
  var what=div.innerHTML
  var hi = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(what);
  hi.pitch = 1;
  hi.rate = 1;
  hi = voice;
  synth.speak(hi);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main" onclick="sayit()"> Hola Mundo </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

I see at least 3 mistakes:

- `speechSynthesis.getVoices()` is a synchronous method, so wrapping in in a Promise does nothing. It's not harmful, just pointless.
- `var voice = getVoz()` - after this, `voice` is now the promise, not the result. However you cannot add `await` here since you are not inside an async function. You need to use `.then()` and a callback.
- `hi = voice;` - this overwrites the entire `hi` variable with the Promise. Probably not what was intended.

Here's how I would write it:

```
function sayit(){
  var hi = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(document.getElementById('main').innerHTML);
  hi.pitch = 1;
  hi.rate = 1;
  hi.voice = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices().find(voz => voz.lang == "es-ES");
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(hi);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more readings, I found a couple of things that solve my problem:

1. the voicelist is loaded async to the page. An onvoiceschanged event is needed.
2. this code works `(await getVoices())`  and the previous one does not `const Voces = await getVoices()`

The following code works

````
let synth = window.speechSynthesis;
let esp= 0
const getVoices = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let voices = synth.getVoices()
        if (voices.length) {
          resolve(voices)
          return
        }
        const voiceschanged = () => {
          voices = synth.getVoices()
          resolve(voices)
        }
        speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = voiceschanged
    })
}

const getVoz = async () => {
  (await getVoices()).forEach(voice => {
    console.log(voice.name, voice.lang)
    if(voice.lang=="es-ES"){
      esp= voice
    }
  })
}
getVoz()

function sayit(){
  let div = document.getElementById('main')
  let what=div.innerHTML
  let hi = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(what);
  hi.pitch = 1;
  hi.rate = 1;
  hi.voice = esp;
  synth.speak(hi);
}```
````